# Prepared Statement Does not Exist

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm attempting to update my calendar's title based on the new user's input.

The variables are as follows:

```
$titleNew = 'New Title'
$titleOld = 'Old Title'
```

The old title exists inside the database and should update accordingly, but with this code I'm getting an error message that says my prepared statement does not exist.

```
$result = pg_prepare($conn, "update", "UPDATE calendar SET title = $1 WHERE title LIKE $2");

$result = pg_execute($conn, "update", array($titleNew, $titleOld));
```

Comment: Did you test `$result` for success on the prepare? What does `pg_last_error()` tell you after `pg_prepare()`?

Comment: You're assuming the prepare call succeeded. You should AT LEAST have soemthing like `$result = pg_prepare(...) or die(pg_last_error());`, or explicitly test $result for boolean false (`if($result === FALSE) ...`. Never EVER assume success with DB operations. Even if your sql statement is syntactically perfect, there's far too many other reasons for failure to NOT check.

Comment: pg_last_error says prepared statement "update" does not exist.

Comment: Is it the result error of the `pg_prepare` execution, or of the `pg_execute`? You need to be sure that the `pg_prepare` is executing without error, so you need the error message returned by the `pg_prepare` method.

Comment: I don't recommend to use a `LIKE` there.

Comment: pg_prepare is saying that the relation calendar does not exist but I insert into it in another connection with the same reference. And what should I use instead of LIKE?

Comment: Make sure you are connected to the same DB. Instead of LIKE use equals... `WHERE title = $2`

Comment: Everything for the connection is the exact same. I also changed the LIKE to equals. The code that I have works if I run it in postgres, but when I run it inside the php it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

To find out, whether the table `calendar` actually exists in the database you are connected to, run in the same session:

```
SELECT n.nspname As schema_name, c.relname As tbl_name
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  c.relname ILIKE 'calendar';
```

I suspect the underlying problem is a confusion with table names or connection parameters.You may have:

- confused the database.
- confused the port.
- a [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) setting that does not include the schema the table lives in.
  Check your search_path with: `SHOW search_path;`
  Is the schema name included?
- misspelled the table name.
- confused a double-quoted mixed-cased name like `"Calendar"` with the (generally preferable) lower case name `calendar`.

If you don't have the actual schema in your `search_path`: Either set the `search_path` properly or *schema-qualify* the table name:

```
UPDATE calendar.calendar SET title = $1 WHERE title = $2
```

Comment: I ran the code and it returned a row schema name: calendar table_name: calendar.

Comment: @user2415335: I added simple query to check the current `search_path` of your session. Follow the link in my answer for more information about the `search_path`.

Comment: I'm just not sure this is right because I have the exact same code with a different query to insert into the table and it works. I copy and pasted it.

Comment: the search_path is calendar so I changed my code to calendar.calendar and it still isn't working.

Comment: @user2415335: If the `search_path` is set to `calendar`, then adding the schema-name to the query is optional. Is `pg_prepare` still saying that the relation `calendar` does not exist? Or do you run into another error? You are aware, that double-quoting preserves the case in Postgres, right? `"Calender"` <> `calendar` ...